# How is a variable returning as "null"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was looking through my code to try and fix a problem, then I came across what was causing it, but I am unable to fix it. As below, I set Move1 to null earlier in the script, and the variable does not change anywhere else in the script other than the two places I am showing you.

```
    private GameObject Move1 = null;
```

The problem is that when I do `Debug.Log(Move)` the first time, it does not return as "null". However, when I call  `Debug.Log(Move)` for the second time, it does return as null and I am unsure why.

```
 private void addVar(GameObject Move, GameObject Cyl)
{
    Debug.Log(Move);
    if (Move1 == null)
    {
        Move = Move1;
        Cyl = Cyl1;
        Moves.Add(Move);
        Movecyls.Add(Cyl);
        Debug.Log(Move);
    }
```

I have already tried doing `private GameObject Move1;` but that doesn't work. That's about all the ideas I have. Thanks!

Comment: You are confusing `Move` and `Move1`?  One is a class variable, the other is a function parameter.  Look for the function calls, and see if the value can be not null.

Comment: You are setting Move1 to null but you are debugging Move

Comment: What are you passing in to addVar as Move? If you pass null it will be null for the first Debug.Log...

Comment: i think you meant to write `if (Move1 != null)` or `if (Move == null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May it be, that you are mixing up `Move = Move1;` and `Move1 = Move;` ?

Answer (score 3):

because you are assigning `Move = Move1;` only when `Move1 == null`

=> `Move = null;`

---

Note in general: You shouldn't use `== null` on Unity built-in types inheriting from [`Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) at all.

Rather use the [implicit operator `bool`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) like e.g.

```
if(!Move1)
{
   ...
```

The reason is that internally `Object` might not be set to a valid reference but will still hold some information about **why** it is returning a value that *equals* `null`. That's the reason why you don't get the usual `NullReferenceException` for Unity types but e.g. `MissingReferenceException`.  It is not really `null` though so a check `== null` might fail in some occasions.

Answer (score 2):

Your code as it stands with some comments on what is happening.

```
private void addVar(GameObject Move, GameObject Cyl)
{
    // The function parameter is whatever sent to this function
    // It may or may not be null
    Debug.Log(Move);
    if (Move1 == null)
    {
        // The following will always result in null
        // Because of the above if condition
        Move = Move1;
        Cyl = Cyl1;
        Moves.Add(Move);
        Movecyls.Add(Cyl);
        // Debug value will now be null
        Debug.Log(Move);
    }

// Other operations
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're logging "Move" at the beginning but it is not defined as null, therefore it wont log as null. The second debug you set it to null since "Move1" is null, that's why you get null the second time.